# Limit of function of $2$ variables

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

> Calculate the following limit (or show it doesn't exist):
>
> $$ \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} x^4 \cdot \sin\left(\frac{1}{x^2+ |y|}\right) $$

My intuition is that the limit is $0$ since it's a bounded function multiply by $x^4$ that goes to $0$, but I need to make it formal.

Comment: You are doing well, just use Squeeze Theorem.

Answer (score 3):

For all $(x,y)\ne (0,0) $,

$$-1\le \sin (\frac {1}{x^2+|y|})\le 1$$

$$\implies $$

$$-x^4 \le f (x,y)\le x^4$$

and squeeze .

Answer (score 0):

The limit doesn't exist simply, because the critical point of $|y|$ is $0$, and limit doesn't exist at critical points of absolute value functions.